# Hibernate JPA - Generate join table in Many-To-Many mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to map a unidirectional Many-To-Many mapping in a legacy oracle database using Hibernate (within a Spring Boot framework if that makes a difference).

The reading I've done so far seems to suggest that there needs to be a join table in the database, which this DB does not have. Is it possible for Hibernate to create a temporary join table in memory 'on the fly' to fulfil its requirements for the mapping? If so then what are the steps - or if not, then what are the alternatives?

Comment: If the DB does not have a join table then I don't think it is many to many. Are you saying the existing schema does not have it or Oracle doesn't support a join table (not likely). Perhaps you should add the schema.

Comment: It definitely is a many-to-many association - Entity A can be associated to multiple Entity Bs, and Entity B can be associated to multiple Entity As.  Regarding the schema, the join table doesn't exist and I won't be allowed to add it to the legacy DB, hence my question as to whether hibernate can generate a temporary join table in memory instead..

Comment: Good, but your question is still not clear. For JPA in memory temp tables, no, not that I'm aware of, and why would you want a temporary persistence table? Kind of defeats the point doesn't it. In terms of DB stuff you can't do a many-to-many in a RDBMS without a join table. So, like I said, you need to explain your question more clearly or rethink your issue. Hope this helps.